# Event doesn't display location on info page

Tags: civievent, location

After creating an event with an address the info page will not display the location nor the map.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are experiencing this it is most likely due to an old event template or you copied an older event. More recent versions of CiviCRM have an option on recurring events to display the location. It is on by default but older events were not retroactively set to On.

To fix this you can create a completely new event or in the mysql database on the civicrm_event table set your event to is_show_location = 1.

Comment: I just got caught with this one. Copied an event, modified it. switch on the display a map option and got no map. Had to go into the database and edit the is_map and is_show-Location fields to get it to show up, despite what the UI was telling me. Bug?